Equation of State using ev.x Package of Quantum ESPRESSO
I have several data points of Energy and Volume of unit cell of hexagonal monolayer. I want to fit Birch-Murnaghan Equation of State to get equilibrium volume. Is it possible to get equilibrium lattice parameter from resulting fitting?
